# Discord.py connect() times out after 60 seconds

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a discord.py rewrite bot that I'm trying to make join a voice channel, but when I make it join using this code:

```
@commands.command()
async def join_voice(self, ctx):
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    await channel.connect()
```

After 60 seconds the bot will always disconnect and send this error:

```
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/discordbotpy/cogs/admin.py", line 42, in join_voice
    await connected.channel.connect() #  Use the channel instance you put into a variable
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/abc.py", line 1154, in connect
    await voice.connect(timeout=timeout, reconnect=reconnect)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/voice_client.py", line 345, in connect
    await utils.sane_wait_for(futures, timeout=timeout)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/utils.py", line 350, in sane_wait_for
    raise asyncio.TimeoutError()
TimeoutError:
```

I'm not sure what to do. I've tried multiple different ways to join, but none of them work.

Comment: Just curious, could the server by chance have a 1 minute AFK timer for voice channels? And if so that may be the cause of the "random" disconnects.

Comment: No, the server has the afk timeout off.

Comment: It appears [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceChannel.connect) that the bot tries to connect for 60 seconds and if that fails then you get the `asyncio.TimeoutError`, I don't think this is a problem with your code.

Comment: Ah, thank you. That makes sense.